# PySpark concat a column of lists over a weekly or monthly timeperiod

Tags: python, pyspark, concatenation, aggregate

I am new to PySpark/Databricks. I have a question related to concatenating a column of lists based on weekly or monthly time-periods. Here is the code I have with expected results.

```
dates = ['2023-04-01', '2023-04-02', '2023-04-03', '2023-04-04', '2023-04-05', '2023-04-06', '2023-04-07', '2023-04-08', '2023-04-09', '2023-04-10', '2023-04-11', '2023-04-12', '2023-04-13', '2023-04-14']
brands = [['bmw', 'vw'], ['chevy', 'buick'], ['nissan', 'lexus', 'buick'], ['bmw', 'nissan', 'lexus'], ['bmw', 'vw', 'nissan', 'lexus'], ['bmw', 'vw', 'chevy'], ['chevy', 'bmw', 'buick'], ['bmw', 'vw'], ['chevy', 'nissan'], ['nissan', 'lexus', 'vw'], ['bmw', 'nissan', 'vw'], ['bmw', 'vw', 'nissan', 'lexus'], ['bmw', 'lexus', 'chevy'], ['chevy', 'bmw', 'buick']]
weights = [[0.99, 0.98], [0.97, 0.96], [0.95, 0.94, 0.93], [0.98, 0.96, 0.95], [0.97, 0.96, 0.95, 0.94], [0.975, 0.964, 0.952], [0.98, 0.976, 0.967],
[0.978, 0.975], [0.928, 0.935], [0.982, 0.961, 0.952], [0.97, 0.96, 0.952], [0.975, 0.964, 0.952, 0.943], [0.982, 0.976, 0.967], [0.992, 0.987, 0.978]]

df = spark.createDataFrame(zip(dates, brands, weights), ['date', 'brands', 'weight'])
df.show()

+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|      date|              brands|              weight|
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|2023-04-01|           [bmw, vw]|        [0.99, 0.98]|
|2023-04-02|      [chevy, buick]|        [0.97, 0.96]|
|2023-04-03|[nissan, lexus, e...|  [0.95, 0.94, 0.93]|
|2023-04-04|[bmw, nissan, lexus]|  [0.98, 0.96, 0.95]|
|2023-04-05|[bmw, vw, nissan,...|[0.97, 0.96, 0.95...|
|2023-04-06|    [bmw, vw, chevy]|[0.975, 0.964, 0....|
|2023-04-07| [chevy, bmw, buick]|[0.98, 0.976, 0.967]|
|2023-04-08|           [bmw, vw]|[0.99, 0.987, 0.978]|
|2023-04-09|     [chevy, nissan]|      [0.978, 0.975]|
|2023-04-10| [nissan, lexus, vw]|      [0.972, 0.963]|
|2023-04-11| [bmw, security, vw]|[0.955, 0.942, 0....|
|2023-04-12|[bmw, vw, nissan,...|[0.982, 0.961, 0....|
|2023-04-13| [bmw, lexus, chevy]|[0.97, 0.96, 0.95...|
|2023-04-14| [chevy, bmw, buick]|[0.975, 0.964, 0....|
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+

df1 = df.withColumn("DateFormatted", to_timestamp(col("date"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
df1.show()
    
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|      date|              brands|              weight|      DateFormatted|
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|2023-04-01|           [bmw, vw]|        [0.99, 0.98]|2023-04-01 00:00:00|
|2023-04-02|      [chevy, buick]|        [0.97, 0.96]|2023-04-02 00:00:00|
|2023-04-03|[nissan, lexus, e...|  [0.95, 0.94, 0.93]|2023-04-03 00:00:00|
|2023-04-04|[bmw, nissan, lexus]|  [0.98, 0.96, 0.95]|2023-04-04 00:00:00|
|2023-04-05|[bmw, vw, nissan,...|[0.97, 0.96, 0.95...|2023-04-05 00:00:00|
|2023-04-06|    [bmw, vw, chevy]|[0.975, 0.964, 0....|2023-04-06 00:00:00|
|2023-04-07| [chevy, bmw, buick]|[0.98, 0.976, 0.967]|2023-04-07 00:00:00|
|2023-04-08|           [bmw, vw]|[0.99, 0.987, 0.978]|2023-04-08 00:00:00|
|2023-04-09|     [chevy, nissan]|      [0.978, 0.975]|2023-04-09 00:00:00|
|2023-04-10| [nissan, lexus, vw]|      [0.972, 0.963]|2023-04-10 00:00:00|
|2023-04-11| [bmw, security, vw]|[0.955, 0.942, 0....|2023-04-11 00:00:00|
|2023-04-12|[bmw, vw, nissan,...|[0.982, 0.961, 0....|2023-04-12 00:00:00|
|2023-04-13| [bmw, lexus, chevy]|[0.97, 0.96, 0.95...|2023-04-13 00:00:00|
|2023-04-14| [chevy, bmw, buick]|[0.975, 0.964, 0....|2023-04-14 00:00:00|
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

I converted the date col into Date column to do any sort of timestamp related aggregation. Now, here is what I want:

1. On a weekly basis (say 1st Apr - 7th Apr, 8th Apr - 14th Apr...), I want the 'brands' column and 'weight' column to be concatenated into just one row (of a new dataframe).
2. I want a another dataframe, monthly_aggregate_df that will do similar stuff, for every calendar month.

I tried these...but, hit several issues:

window(column, window duration, sliding duration, starting offset)

```
    df2 = df1.groupBy(window(col("DateFormatted"), "1 week", "1 week", "64 hours")).agg(concat("brands") as "brands_concat").select("window.start", "window.end", "DateFormatted", "brands_concat").show()

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<command-4423978228267630>", line 2
    df2 = df1.groupBy(window(col("DateFormatted"), "1 week", "1 week", "64 hours")).agg(concat("brands") as "brands_concat").select("window.start", "window.end", "DateFormatted", "brands_concat").show()
                                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Another try:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.groupBy("date").agg(f.concat_ws(",", f.collect_list("brands")).alias("brands")).show()


AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'concat_ws(',', collect_list(`brands`))' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires (array<string> or string) type, however, 'collect_list(`brands`)' is of array<array<string>> type.;
```

Looks like concat_ws concats only strings. Not lists. Maybe I need to use some sort of UDF to do this. So, tried array_join..but, doesn't like to work with grouped-data...

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_join
    df2.withColumn("week_strt_day",date_sub(next_day(col("DateFormatted"),"sunday"),7)).groupBy("week_strt_day").apply(array_join("brands", ",").alias("brands")).orderBy("week_strt_day").show()
    
    ValueError: Invalid udf: the udf argument must be a pandas_udf of type GROUPED_MAP.
```

Comment: Please add expected output based on your example inputs

Comment: you need `.agg(concat("brands").alias("brands_concat"))` instead of using `as` keyword like sql.

Comment: When you have issues with function, just look at the official doc : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/functions.html

Answer (score 3):

1. You format the data:

- String Date to timestamp
- zip of both array

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df1 = df.select(
    F.to_timestamp(F.col("date"), "yyyy-MM-dd").alias("DateFormatted"),
    F.arrays_zip(F.col("weight"), F.col("brands")).alias("data"),
)
```

```py
df1.show()
+-------------------+--------------------+
|      DateFormatted|                data|
+-------------------+--------------------+
|2023-04-01 00:00:00|[{0.99, bmw}, {0....|
|2023-04-02 00:00:00|[{0.97, chevy}, {...|
|2023-04-03 00:00:00|[{0.95, nissan}, ...|
|2023-04-04 00:00:00|[{0.98, bmw}, {0....|
|2023-04-05 00:00:00|[{0.97, bmw}, {0....|
|2023-04-06 00:00:00|[{0.975, bmw}, {0...|
|2023-04-07 00:00:00|[{0.98, chevy}, {...|
|2023-04-08 00:00:00|[{0.978, bmw}, {0...|
|2023-04-09 00:00:00|[{0.928, chevy}, ...|
|2023-04-10 00:00:00|[{0.982, nissan},...|
|2023-04-11 00:00:00|[{0.97, bmw}, {0....|
|2023-04-12 00:00:00|[{0.975, bmw}, {0...|
|2023-04-13 00:00:00|[{0.982, bmw}, {0...|
|2023-04-14 00:00:00|[{0.992, chevy}, ...|
+-------------------+--------------------+
```

2. You aggregate the values by weeks :

```py
df2 = df1.groupBy(
    F.window(F.col("DateFormatted"), "1 weeks")
    .getItem("start")
    .cast("date")
    .alias("week")
).agg(F.collect_list(F.col("data")).alias("data"),).select(
    "week", F.reverse(F.array_sort(F.flatten(F.col("data")))).alias("data")
)
```

```py
df2.show(truncate=False)
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|week      |data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2023-03-30|[{0.99, bmw}, {0.98, vw}, {0.98, bmw}, {0.975, bmw}, {0.97, chevy}, {0.97, bmw}, {0.964, vw}, {0.96, vw}, {0.96, nissan}, {0.96, buick}, {0.952, chevy}, {0.95, nissan}, {0.95, nissan}, {0.95, lexus}, {0.94, lexus}, {0.94, lexus}, {0.93, buick}]                                                       |
|2023-04-06|[{0.982, nissan}, {0.982, bmw}, {0.98, chevy}, {0.978, bmw}, {0.976, lexus}, {0.976, bmw}, {0.975, vw}, {0.975, bmw}, {0.97, bmw}, {0.967, chevy}, {0.967, buick}, {0.964, vw}, {0.961, lexus}, {0.96, nissan}, {0.952, vw}, {0.952, vw}, {0.952, nissan}, {0.943, lexus}, {0.935, nissan}, {0.928, chevy}]|
|2023-04-13|[{0.992, chevy}, {0.987, bmw}, {0.978, buick}]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

3. You repeat `2.` for month :

```py
df3 = df1.groupBy(F.date_format(F.col("DateFormatted"), "YYYY-MM").alias("month")).agg(
    F.collect_list(F.col("data")).alias("data"),
).select("month", F.reverse(F.array_sort(F.flatten(F.col("data")))).alias("data"))
```

```py
df3.show(truncate=False)
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|month  |data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2023-04|[{0.992, chevy}, {0.99, bmw}, {0.987, bmw}, {0.982, nissan}, {0.982, bmw}, {0.98, vw}, {0.98, chevy}, {0.98, bmw}, {0.978, buick}, {0.978, bmw}, {0.976, lexus}, {0.976, bmw}, {0.975, vw}, {0.975, bmw}, {0.975, bmw}, {0.97, chevy}, {0.97, bmw}, {0.97, bmw}, {0.967, chevy}, {0.967, buick}, {0.964, vw}, {0.964, vw}, {0.961, lexus}, {0.96, vw}, {0.96, nissan}, {0.96, nissan}, {0.96, buick}, {0.952, vw}, {0.952, vw}, {0.952, nissan}, {0.952, chevy}, {0.95, nissan}, {0.95, nissan}, {0.95, lexus}, {0.943, lexus}, {0.94, lexus}, {0.94, lexus}, {0.935, nissan}, {0.93, buick}, {0.928, chevy}]|
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

If you need brand and weight in 2 different columns, you can simply use this :

```py
df3.select(
    "month",
    F.col("data.brands"),
    F.col("data.weight"),
).show()

+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  month|              brands|              weight|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
|2023-04|[chevy, bmw, bmw,...|[0.992, 0.99, 0.9...|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Steven. Instead of having an arbitrary week identifier, is there a way to have the start of the week? Something like this :

df1 = df1.withColumn("week_strt_day",date_sub(next_day(col("DateFormatted"),"sunday"),7))

Comment: Also, if one has to have the brand-list in descending order of weight, that would be nice. The "collect_list" aggregation, as designed, will concatenate the list. Is there a nice way to concatenate the lists and order them based on the weights?

Comment: @user1717931 it's not an arbitrary week identifier. It's the date of the first day of the week. As I said in the **NB**, I have a 2 hours shift, therefore the date `2023-03-30 02:00` is in fact `2023-03-30 00:00` which is a sunday (start of the week in US format). You end up with a timestamp that you can cast to string in the format you want/need.

Comment: @user1717931 you cannot have the brand order according to the weight as the number of weight of each line does not match the number of brands. See line `2023-04-10| [nissan, lexus, vw]|      [0.972, 0.963]`

Comment: You are right. I did not see the input data closely enough. I have corrected the input lists now..and there brands and weights match properly.

Comment: @user1717931 I updated the answer. Check the result again

Answer (score 3):

Let me know what you think of this solution:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('2023-04-01', ['bmw', 'vw'], [0.99, 0.98]),
    ('2023-04-02', ['bmw', 'chevy'], [0.96, 0.95]),
    ('2023-04-03', ['bmw', 'nissan', 'lexus'], [0.98, 0.96, 0.95]),
    ('2023-04-04', ['chevy', 'bmw', 'buick'], [0.98, 0.976, 0.967]),
    ('2023-04-05', ['nissan', 'lexus', 'vw'], [0.972, 0.963, 0.98]),
    ('2023-05-06', ['bmw', 'vw'], [0.99, 0.98]),
    ('2023-05-07', ['bmw', 'chevy'], [0.96, 0.95]),
], ['Date', 'Brands', 'Weights'])

df_grouped_weekly = (
    df
    .withColumn('DateFormatted', f.to_timestamp(f.col('Date'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
    .withColumn('WeekOfYear', f.concat_ws('-', f.weekofyear(f.col('DateFormatted')), f.year(f.col('DateFormatted'))))
    .groupBy('WeekOfYear')
    .agg(
        f.collect_list(f.col('Brands')).alias('GroupedBrands'),
        f.collect_list(f.col('Weights')).alias('GroupedWeights'),
    )
    .withColumn('GroupedBrands', f.flatten(f.col('GroupedBrands')))
    .withColumn('GroupedWeights', f.flatten(f.col('GroupedWeights')))
)

df_grouped_monthly = (
    df
    .withColumn('DateFormatted', f.to_timestamp(f.col('Date'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
    .withColumn('Month', f.concat_ws('-', f.month(f.col('DateFormatted')), f.year(f.col('DateFormatted'))))
    .groupBy('Month')
    .agg(
        f.collect_list(f.col('Brands')).alias('GroupedBrands'),
        f.collect_list(f.col('Weights')).alias('GroupedWeights'),
    )
    .withColumn('GroupedBrands', f.flatten(f.col('GroupedBrands')))
    .withColumn('GroupedWeights', f.flatten(f.col('GroupedWeights')))
)

df_grouped_weekly.show(truncate = False)
df_grouped_monthly.show(truncate = False)
```

The output is:

```
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|WeekOfYear|GroupedBrands                                             |GroupedWeights                                            |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|18-2023   |[bmw, vw, bmw, chevy]                                     |[0.99, 0.98, 0.96, 0.95]                                  |
|14-2023   |[bmw, nissan, lexus, chevy, bmw, buick, nissan, lexus, vw]|[0.98, 0.96, 0.95, 0.98, 0.976, 0.967, 0.972, 0.963, 0.98]|
|13-2023   |[bmw, vw, bmw, chevy]                                     |[0.99, 0.98, 0.96, 0.95]                                  |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+

+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Month |GroupedBrands                                                                  |GroupedWeights                                                                    |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|4-2023|[bmw, vw, bmw, chevy, bmw, nissan, lexus, chevy, bmw, buick, nissan, lexus, vw]|[0.99, 0.98, 0.96, 0.95, 0.98, 0.96, 0.95, 0.98, 0.976, 0.967, 0.972, 0.963, 0.98]|
|5-2023|[bmw, vw, bmw, chevy]                                                          |[0.99, 0.98, 0.96, 0.95]                                                          |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Is there a way to order the items in GroupedBrands by their respective weights in descending order? And, likewise, have the GroupedWeights in desc order...without messing up the (brand, weight) pairings? I understand this is not part of my initial question, but, this is an afterthought...

Comment: Yes, you can use `arrays_zip` to create an array of struct, and then sort it.

Comment: Given the fact that values in GroupedBrands are not unique, using `map_from_arrays` is a better idea.